# Error while running app in real device in ionic v3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am a newbie to Ionic 3.
I am trying to run it on real a device using below CLI:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

It runs perfectly before I added firebase in it.

I want firebase token for notification.

I followed the instructions at https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase/

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use firebase in an ionic project, then use the following plugin:

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

> Your Android build may fail if you are installing multiple plugins that use the Google Play Services library.
>   This is caused by plugins installing different versions of the Google Play Services library.
>   This can be resolved by installing cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release which enables you to override the versions specified by other plugins in order to align them.

Comment: Same error : `* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.1,17.2.1]], but resolves to 17.2.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.`

Comment: `What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.1,17.2.1]], but resolves to 17.2.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.`

Comment: download this plugin  cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205855/discussion-between-unnati-patadia-and-peter-haddad).

Comment: @UnnatiPatadia Since the answer helped you please mark it as correct and upvote it, thank you!